# Check if active element has particular class via javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a single-field form and want the Enter key to advance the form to the next input field. Since there's another form on the page, I only want the Enter key to advance the form when one of the inputs in that form is the `activeElement`.

I've achieved this with what seems like an extremely verbose `if()` statement here:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
        var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
        var ids = [ 'this', 'that', 'there', 'thing', 'other' ];
        if ( document.getElementById( ids[0] ) === document.activeElement || document.getElementById( ids[1] ) === document.activeElement || document.getElementById( ids[2] ) === document.activeElement || document.getElementById( ids[3] ) === document.activeElement || document.getElementById( ids[4] ) === document.activeElement) {
            if( keyCode === 13 ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                self._nextQuestion();
            }
        }
    } );
```

Each of the inputs are the same class: `.questions`. I've tried something like:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
    var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
    var ids = [ 'this', 'that', 'there', 'thing', 'other' ];
    if ( document.querySelector('.questions') === document.activeElement) {
        if( keyCode === 13 ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            self._nextQuestion();
        }
    }
} );
```

But of course, this only accesses the first instance of `.questions` on the page. I don't want to iterate over nodes, as it doesn't seem much better than what I have already.

I'm a novice, and I'm looking for more concise logic.

Comment: Could you check `document.activeElement.className`, maybe using `.indexOf`?

Comment: And does the forms have id's or anything else to distinguish them? If so, just listen on the form rather than the document

Comment: Yes it has an id and a class, but when the cursor is in the input it is the only `activeElement`, not the form.

Comment: My point being, the event bubbles, first to the form, then to the document, if you only want to capture key events on one form, use a selector to target that form,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check if the `activeElement` has the `questions` class.

```
var pattern = /(?:^|\s)questions(?:\s|$)/
if (document.activeElement.className.match(pattern)) {
  ...
}
```

squint provided an improved regex that will account for more funky situations in the classname.

Comment: FYI: `document.activeElement.classList.contains('questions')`

Comment: Simpler, but loses < IE10 compatibility

Comment: The regex can fail in some cases since there are valid class characters that would be seen as a word boundary. To use a regex, I think you'd need to do `/(?:^|\s)questions(?:\s|$)/`

Comment: That's a good point squint. I think either qzx's approach or just `split`ting would be best then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: qxz's solution has a similar problem in that it only accounts for one kind of space character. It should technically include tabs and newlines too, as unlikely as they may be, which makes the regex handy.

Comment: For those interested in why you wouldn't use `document.activeElement.className === "foo"`, please see the comments in my own answer on this page.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if ((" "+document.activeElement.className+" ").indexOf(" questions ") > -1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can utilise `classList` api to check element for given className presence, e.g. `document.activeElement && document.activeElement.classList.contains('question')`.

All the proposed approaches are really helpful and should fix the problem. On the other hand, you might want to keep you application's state in one place so you can manage it easily. By doing so, you make your application more predictable and easier to debug.

Here's an approach you might want to take:

HTML Code:

```
<input class="question" value="1"/>
<input class="question" value="2"/>
<input class="question" value="3"/>
<input class="question" value="4"/>
<input class="question" value="5"/>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var component = {
  activeQuestion: 0,
  questionSelector: '.question',
  get activeQuestionElement () {
    return component.allQuestionElements[component.activeQuestion];
  },
  get allQuestionElements () {
    return document.querySelectorAll(component.questionSelector);
  },
  next: function () {
    var activeElement = document.activeElement;

    if (activeElement && activeElement === component.activeQuestionElement && component.allQuestionElements[component.activeQuestion+1]) {
      component.activeQuestion++;
      component.highlightQuestion();
    }
  },
  highlightQuestion: function () {
    component.activeQuestionElement.focus();
  },
  install: function () {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        component.next.call(component);
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      var className = component.questionSelector.slice(1);

      if (event.target.classList.contains(className)) {
        component.activeQuestion = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(component.questionSelector)).indexOf(event.target);
        component.highlightQuestion();
      }
    })
  }
};

component.install();
```

As you can see above, `component` is a single object instance that holds useful information like `activeQuestion` index, question selector, some computed properties that return DOM elements. The `install` method binds event listeners which manage the state when events occur.

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/maciejsmolinski/xzyvye8z/embedded/result/

When you click `enter` when any of the fields is focused, it is going to move focus to the next one. In addition to that, clicking on any of the fields changes active question as well. You can easily alter the behaviour by modifying the code I posted above. It is just a basic skeleton you can use to build your own functionality on top of.

This is a very basic component. You can build anything on top of it. You can introduce ES6 syntax (classes, arrow functions, `const` instead of `var`) but I intentionally left that part untouched to make it easier to understand.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You guys pointed me in the right direction with `document.activeElement.className`, so I upvoted all who mentioned it, but the most concise solution that works here seems to be this:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
        var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
        // enter
        if ( document.activeElement.className === 'questions') {
            if( keyCode === 13 ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                self._nextQuestion();
            }
        }
    } );
```

I'll give you guys some time to critique this before I mark it as the answer...

Comment: This fails if the `activeElement` has more than one class.

Comment: @CollinD, can you explain this a bit further? Do you mean if there is more than one instance of the class? Or do you mean there is more than one class active at a time?

Comment: the `className` of an element such as `<div class="foo bar baz">` is in fact, `foo bar baz`. For querying purposes (css, `document.querySelector` etc), it has all 3 of those classes. But if you just checked `className === "foo"` it would fail.

Comment: Ok, I know what you're saying. The element has only one `className` and I can't see that changing. Is there any reason that doing it this way would make it a bad practice with that in mind?

Comment: Fixing it now costs almost zero effort, and prevents a very confusing bug as your project develops. But that's up to you as the maintainer. Just seems unnecessary to box yourself in (and I know I've siad "that's not going to change" on enough projects to zip it when i start to these days). This solution is just lacking in general and provides less utility to others that may find this question. I'd at least edit to provide a note that it will not work with elements that have multiple classes, or whitespace around the class name. `className === 'foo bar baz'` is just as bad. Cant rearrange them.

Comment: Ok, that's good enough for me and hopefully instructive discourse for visitors. I'll accept your answer. I'm also not very satisfied with the title of this post. Any ideas there?